# QGIS - Restore Warning on Delete Rows

Tags: qgis

I am developing a project for users to edit data in a PostGIS database using QGIS 3.28.10.

While testing, on attempting to delete a row from a table, QGIS offered a helpful warning dialog along the lines of "Are you sure you want to delete these rows" which was accompanied by a check box "Do not show this warning again".

I absent mindedly ticked the checkbox so now the warning is not provided before deleting rows.

I would like to restore the warning but have searched both online and within QGIS help and checked the config and am unable to find the option to do so.

Can you advise how I can restore the option to show a warning before deleting rows from a PostGIS table in QGIS 3.28.10

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This warning was introduced in 3.28. Check [this PR](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/pull/49977) for more info.

There was some opinions about hiding or not how to uncheck the "not ask again option".

To it go to `Settings -> Options -> Advanced` and click in `I will be carefull`.

Then use the search bar to look for `showDeletionWarning` and check/uncheck it.

[image]